# How can C/C++ #define directives be visualised?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, ide, c-preprocessor

I am looking for ways to visualize the effects of #define's - For example that code not seen by the compiler is shown in a different color.

Primarily visual studio, but nice to know about other environments?
Ideally, also code seen by the compiler, but will not be run.

Comment: If your IDE can understand how the file will be compiled, then it should be able to do that. Probably CLion can do that as well.

Comment: Most modern IDEs do have some form of syntax highlighting that recognises preprocessor directives.   I'm not aware of any that will do what you want.  Practically, the logic to identify code that has been removed by the preprocessor would be computationally too expensive to run in an IDE (slow down echoing of input, etc) and probably get things wrong too often to be useful.  A number of IDEs do handle some simple cases (e.g. greying out text wrapped in `#ifdef 0` and `#endif`) but you're seeking much more than that.  Main tip:  don't rely excessively on the preprocessor.

Comment: @Peter At least Visual Studio 2015 and later do this properly. I don't agree that letting the preprocessor run over a source file (and, implicitly, its includes) is costly. Of course you don't want to do it after every key stroke but this is pretty trivial stuff to get right.

Comment: I don't understand the question with regards to Visual Studio. It [already does exactly what you ask for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68jN0.png), so what's the question? Going by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586672/disable-or-fix-ifdef-sensitive-colouring-and-intellisense-in-visual-studio) random Q/A, it exists since at least VS2005 and works much better since VS2010.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - I didn't say running the preprocessor is costly.   I said that the logic to characterise how it changes the code would be, in order to identify and display/highlight the deltas.   For simple cases, yeah okay.   But for macros that do token pasting, stringification, and the like, the notion of "removed" is a lot more nebulous.  And there are many other things the preprocessor can do.

Comment: @MaxLanghof that's an answer!  Will try to add it in my project settings.

Comment: @Peter Calculating everything is perhaps expensive, but the main usecase is checking the effect of single defines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio does this already by default, at least since VS2005 and much better since VS2010 (going by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586672/disable-or-fix-ifdef-sensitive-colouring-and-intellisense-in-visual-studio) Q/A):

[image]

Edit: Added in response to another answer:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

One way is to see the source after the preprocessing, using *gcc* (for C) or *g++* (for c++) just use the option `-E`

For instance having the file `p.cc`

```
#ifdef FOO
# define BAR 1
#else
# define BAR 2
#endif

int main()
{
  return BAR;
}
```

if I do without defining  *FOO* I have :

```
/tmp % gcc -E p.cc
# 1 "p.cc"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "p.cc"

int main()
{
  return 2;
}
```

if I do defining  *FOO* I have :

```
/tmp % gcc -DFOO -E p.cc
# 1 "p.cc"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "p.cc"

int main()
{
  return 1;
}
```

---

Note : you probably have `#include` in your source so after the preprocessing you get a lot of lines coming from the included files, for the question [How to show 'preprocessed' code ignoring includes with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891248/how-to-show-preprocessed-code-ignoring-includes-with-gcc/54891562) I put an answer to bypass them.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i visualise C/C++ #define's?

Short answer: in general **you cannot** (and notice that you don't define what "visualize" means in your question). You really want to look at the preprocessed form. With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) you practically get it with `gcc -C -E`.

As a provocative example, `__TIME__` or `__LINE__` is a [*preprocessor magic predefined macro*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) (and so is the `__COUNT__` which is a GCC extension). You are allowed to code

```
#if __LINE__ % 2 == 0
printf("hello from line %d\n", __LINE__);
#endif
```

and the behavior depends upon where that weird code is located (on an even-numbered line, or an odd-numbered one).

Ok, that example is contrived, but legal. Check by reading the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

You could also imagine some `#if __TIME__[1] == '2'` but probably that won't compile (because preprocessor expressions cannot use the `[]` indexing). However, some `if (_TIME__[5] == '2') printf("hello\n");` would compile (and be optimized differently, depending on the moment you are compiling it).

And in practice, code nearly as contrived as the one above does exist. A good example of C code using a lot various preprocessor features is the Linux [kernel source](https://www.kernel.org/) code (you might be interested by [coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/), a tool knowing that). The first step of its build (using `make config` or `make menuconfig`) generates a lot of headers defining the features of your particular kernel. There are many thousands of such configuration options (my `/boot/config-4.19.0-3-amd64` has 7352 configuration choices, and each of them translates to some preprocessor macro used in `#if`).

Comment: How is your example a problem for the feature in question? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx3Du.png

Comment: It just requires the entire preprocessed form to be available.

Comment: That is also true for both intellisense-esque things and the actual compiler (and in both cases preprocessing a single TU should not take a significant amount of time). But I guess we both have different ideas of what "visualize `#define`s" implies.

Comment: Yes, certainly.